# How is List.Clear() implemented in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, memory

I assume it uses an array to implement List. How is `List.Clear()` implemented?
Does it actually clean up the array or just make a new array for this list?

```
public class List {

    private Array _array;

    public void Clear1 () {
        _array.length = 0;
    }
    public void Clear2 () {
        _array = new Array();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: If you populate a list with a lot of values, it can be nice to know whether reusing that list will potentially cause more memory overhead (by holding on to the array), or more performance overhead (by requiring array resizing all over again).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like this (using .NET Reflector):

```
public void Clear()
{
    if (this._size > 0)
    {
        Array.Clear(this._items, 0, this._size);
        this._size = 0;
    }
    this._version++;
}
```

As you see, it just clears the same array. It probably assumes that if you're reusing the same list, you'll probably want to refill it with roughly the same amount of data. If you want to release the array, you'll need to create a new List instance.

Answer (score 14):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a.aspx):

> Count is set to 0, and references to
>   other objects from elements of the
>   collection are also released.
>
> Capacity remains unchanged. To reset
>   the capacity of the List, call the
>   TrimExcess method or set the Capacity
>   property directly. Decreasing the
>   capacity reallocates memory and copies
>   all the elements in the List.
>   Trimming an empty List sets the
>   capacity of the List to the default
>   capacity.
>
> This method is an O(n) operation,
>   where n is Count.

Answer (score 7):

As of .NET 4.0, it does the following:

1. Zeros out the backing array with an `Array.Clear` call. This effectively makes it an O(n) operation.
2. Sets size to 0.
3. Increments the internal version number so that active enumerators will throw `InvalidOperationExceptions` if `MoveNext` is called on them.