# collection Clear() vs new, GC impact

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

i create a bunch of MemoryStreams in a loop and add them to a collection (an ArrayList in this case).
afterwards i iterate over this list and process thise streams.
because i ran into Outofmemoryexceptions, i decided to instead periodically process the list, and free it.

doing this via `list = new ArrayList()` however did nothing to change the memoryconsumption, neither when monitoring it, nor in eliminating the Outofmemoryexceptions. even calling GC.Collect() didn't change that. i noticed that the memory was only freed after leaving the scope.

calling `List.Clear()`however, immediately freed the memory and the loop worked as expected.

so, why this difference? a number of other topics here leave the impression that the two methods should be essentially the same, with `list = new ArrayList()` being possibly more efficient, since Clear() is a O(n) operation.

i'm pretty sure that there are no other references to my memorystreams extant (i basically do `list.Add(new MemoryStream(...)`)

Comment: Not an answer, but detail-related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358129/how-is-list-clear-implemented-in-c

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there is *no* additional strongly reachable reference for the old list? And is the code built for Debug or Release? Debug-mode can have an effect of "hanging onto" references longer than might be expected, as can accidentally keeping a reference to the old list alive. If such is the case, having the references "cleared" indirectly via List.Clear might not be prone to the same effect.

Comment: being at home, i don't have access to the real code right now, but i'm pretty sure i haven't overlooked another reference. but the Debug mode could probably be the culprit. anyway, i'd expect the GC to do it's stuff if at all possible before an exception occurs...

Comment: As would I, which is why I suspect that the old List (or Lists) are strongly-reachable somehow, somewhere - which would in turn keep the items contained strongly reachable and thus prevent the GC from reclaiming them. If such is the case then simply clearing the list would "solve" the problem, as the List itself no longer strongly references the previous elements, even if it was itself kept strongly reachable. (Or it could be a strange oddity *shrug*.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, there *is* a difference.  ArrayList.Clear() sets all the elements to null.  Which makes those elements immediately eligible for collection.

If you reallocate the ArrayList then it matters exactly when the original ArrayList gets collected.  Only *then* will the elements get collected as well.  If the original ArrayList is large (more than 7083 items) then its underlying array is going to end up in the Large Object Heap.  Which doesn't get collected very often.  So the elements stay around for a while as well.  Increasing the odds for OOM.

You ought to look at the big picture here, your program is teetering on the edge of still being able to do its job.  That rarely gets better over time.  You'll need to seriously consider a drastic rewrite, one that, say, halves the VM usage so you'll have some breathing room for a while.  Or take the drastically simple solution.  Flip the switch and target a 64-bit operating system.  Widely available today.

Comment: you are right, of course, and i've since rewritten that code to be more resource friendly. i was just wondering about the different behaviour. and if you'll look at my own answer, there's even a difference when the new is at the end or start of the loop...

Answer (score 1):

In debug mode the JIT extends the lifetime of all local variables (physically: stack locations and registers holding references) to the end of the function. You can see random object lifetime extensions.

This behavior does not violate GC guarantees. A GC which never deletes anything is a valid GC, albeit not a useful one.

Explicitly clearing variables to null and factoring out functions can help here.

When you overwrite a reference variable with `list = new ArrayList()` there might still be other object references to the old list. They might be explicit somewhere in your code, or just random local variables that happen to still hold the old reference but are unused.

Closures are also prone to capture references.

Answer (score 0):

following @user2864740 's comment, i wrote a little test routine and they're right: **the effect does only appear in Debug mode**. Furthermore, only if i `new` the list at the *end* of the loop, not when the same statement is moved to the beginning:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\tststream.123", false, Encoding.Default))
            for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 20); i++) 
                w.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid());

        List<MemoryStream> list = new List<MemoryStream>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:\tststream.123")));
            }
            list = new List<MemoryStream>();
            Console.WriteLine(j.ToString());
        }
    }
```

this throws outofmemory (in 32bit, of course) when compiled in debug mode, on the second iteration. compile it in release or move the `list = new List<MemoryStream>();` to the beginning of the loop, and it continues "indefinitely".